# Problems to Update data in Mysql (Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having problems trying to update information in a mysql table. This problem had not happened to me before when I used the UPDATE statement.
I will show you the code that I have and the error that results:

MODEL:

```
class Pay {
    public function __construct() {}

    public function Users ($id, $idem, $c_user, $num_pay, $total_pay) {

        require_once "../../model/Conexion.php";

        global $conexion;

        $update = "UPDATE Users SET Users = $c_user, num_pay = $num_pay, total_pay = $total_pay WHERE id_user = $id AND idem = $idem";

        $query = $conexion->query($update);
        return $query;

    }
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
$obj = new Pay();

$resp = $obj->UsersCount(5, 5);

$cant = $resp->fetch_object();

$Cant = 1 + $cant->Users;

$num_pay = $cant->num_pay + 1;

$total_pay = $cant->total_pay + 75;

$UserPlus = $obj->Users(5, 5, $Cant, 
$num_pay, $total_pay);
```

THE RESULT:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\solventas\dashboard\Modelos\Pay.php:130 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\solventas\dashboard\Modelos\PaY.php(203): Pay->Users(5, 5, 3, 2, 150.9) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\solventas\dashboard\Modelos\Pay.php on line 130

When trying to do the UPDATE I get that error, and the update is not done. I have checked the code several times and nothing. The UsersCount function if it extracts results but the Users function is the one that has the problem, I do not know why, before that did not happen to me. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use parameters!  Don't munge query strings with values that might cause syntax errors.

Comment: Your connection doesn't exist. Without seeing Conexion.php, it's hard to pinpoint why.

Comment: The connection is include in the scope of the function, so `$conexion` isn't defined in the global scope (I assume).  I would also recommend to learn about dependency injection and pass a connection to the constructor rather than use `require_once()` in the middle of code.

Comment: Code uses a pattern which appears to be vulnerable to SQL Injection.  Little Bobby Tables   https://xkcd.com/327/  OWASP  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Gordon Linoff Yes, identify a problem concerning that which you already solve, but follow another sentence error. I solved the problem, Nigel Ren  you totally right The connection is included in the scope of the function and that isn't work. I have made some changes and that's working now. Thanks for your Recommend about the dependency injection, I'm going to take it in consider and change somethings in my code. Thanks all of you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Your global variable `$conexion` don't initialize. I would also recommend using Singleton for your database connection.